# Boundedness of the function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let $x\in(0,1)$ and $S_{n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$. Then define $f$ as the following :$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{nx^n}{S_{n-1}}-1\right|$$
I need to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ exists. Or at least, I want to show that $f$ is bounded on the given interval. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I suspect that the summation starts at $n=2$ and not $n=1$. Am I correct ?

Comment: sum does not change in both cases. First term comes zero in case of $n=1$.

Comment: Sorry ! I misread ! I thought that you gave the definition of $S_n$ while it is for $S_{n-1}$

Comment: The terms of the series don't converge to $0$. We have, for any fixed $x\in (0,1)$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{nx^n}{S_{n-1}} = 0$$

Comment: then for any fixed $x$ the series may converge to function f. I dont understand when general term does not converge.

Comment: The series diverges for every $x\in (0,1)$. $f$ does not exist.

Comment: For any fixed $x$, general term tends to zero while general term is not uniformly convergent to 0. I dont wonder whether the series converges uniformly. I only wonder whether the series convergent (so f is defined on given interval) and f is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
$$1<1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}<n,x\in(0,1)$$
so
$$x^n-1<\dfrac{nx^n}{1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}}-1<nx^n-1$$
and we know
$\sum_{n=1}x^n,\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n}$ are converge
then you know?

Comment: can we  take $0^0=1$?

Comment: which use  $0^0?$

Comment: besides the general term is nonnegative for each $x$. But the series of the bound on the right side is $\sum nx^n-1\to -\infty$. How it does?

Comment: Left is also $\to-\infty$

Comment: how the sum of a series with nonnegative terms may be less than zero?

Comment: this series is $<0$,because $\dfrac{nx^n}{1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}}<1$

Comment: for any fixed $x $, is it true that  $\dfrac{nx^n}{1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}}<1$?

Comment: I think, your proof is correct for this series. Unfortunately, my original series was $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{nx^n}{S_{n-1}}-1\right|$. so if general term of the series above is negative for all n and $x\in(0,1)$, then my original series goes to positive infinity. Is is right?

Comment: math110, does my original series with absolute valued terms go to positive infinity? Is it right?